# unit testing material ui components with jest

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

There is a grid component in material ui and I want it to be unit tested using jest in my React application. Please find my code below

For the above code, how we will write unit test?  I went through their testing guide https://material-ui.com/guides/testing, but it is not clear.Any ideas/suggestions are really appreciated

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";

import "./styles.scss";

const styles = theme => ({
    root: {
      flexGrow: 1
    },
    paper: {
      height: 140,
      width: 100
    }
});

function Space({ classes }) {
  const x = [1, 2, 3];

  return (
    <div className="center">
      <Grid container className={classes.root}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Grid container justify="center" spacing={Number(32)}>
            {x.map(value => (
              <Grid key={value} item>
                <Paper className={classes.paper} />
              </Grid>
            ))}
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I should be able to unit test the above code using jest

Answer (score 0):

People might hate me for saying this. Since this case does not contain any logic I would just export the function, setup props which reflect real data, and make a snapshot of your shallow rendered function.

Whenever it changes, check it before you update it and all is okay.

EDIT: export the normal component without the withStyles HOC and add the classes to your mocked props.
ANOTHER EDIT:

Your test should probably look something like this in this case:

```
describe('SpaceComponent', () => {
  it('it renders the component correctly', () => {
    const props = { classes: { root: 'root', paper: 'paper' } };
    const component = shallow(<Space {...props} />);
    expect(component).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution, is there any pseudo code? this is something new to me